# Ubuntu 14.04 factory reset

Tags: 14.04, reset

I need to make a factory reset on my **DELL** (`Ubuntu 14.04`) and I'm new to Linux. The laptop is new and I found a `Factory_image.iso`.

How to use this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should look up how to reset OS to factory settings with your laptop's model on youtube because every laptop is different!
if it didn't work try enabling that option in the bios options and if you are completely missing just reply to me with your model number :)

EDIT: you can create a bootable iso image from your USB using UNetbootin
you can install it on Ubuntu using the following command

```
sudo apt-get install unetbootin
```

and launch it by typing "unetbootin" in the terminal without quotes

when done follow the next steps :

> 1. select disk image when you launch UNetbootin
> 2. click the `square` and go to the folder where you have the `iso` and select it
> 3. connect your USB (WARNING:it will format your flash drive backup any important data ) then select your flash drive in the "Drive:" section
> 4. hit **OK** and wait

Comment: Dell inspiron 5558

Comment: did you say that you had an iso file ?

Comment: Yeah, in my downloads appears this iso file

Comment: i just edited the procces if it didnt work we might have to create a vm

Comment: Okay, thanks for all, and sorry for my bad english, it's not my first language

Comment: it is  ok , update me if it worked

Comment: I have a little big problem... I can't connect my laptop to internet because a package (from ethernet) of updates it was corrupt, and taskbar doesn't show me the internet connection... And that's why I need to use "reset factory "

Comment: I have an idea: I can use unetbootin from another laptop, and move with a USB that iso image then I can use to my Dell. Can it works? Then when I "burn" that iso image what I should do with USB?

Comment: the should work